# Size limit for array in UITableviewController

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, web-services, uitableview

I populate the tableview using the data from the webservice.

Now lets say. Initially I got the 20 objects in array. So I populated 20 cells in table.

Now I scroll up the tableview and reach the last cell. Then I call webservice to call more records. This time I again got 20 records. So I populate them to table view.

Now I have array count equal to 40. If this goes on. The array size will go on increasing, which might create performance issue or memory issue.

So please tell me what is the best approach to handle this situation when I am working on native code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good and right, now it creates some cell reload problem when you have image in cell which are downloaded from server. So the best approach is add you data in array as you have describe. Just check if your cell is nil then set all data to that cell, and if cell is nil then just return cell, don't do any thing for that cell. It will just refresh your all downloaded set of array's data. In you case it will reload first 10 cell, and for next 11-20 data it will skip 0-9 cell and load from 10-19 cell.

Comment: But the problem still persists. The array size will go on increasing. As initially it contained 10 objects. Now it contains 20. The number will go on increasing. Am I write or missing something. So I want the way so that we don't need to go on adding data in an array.